# How can I take the name of my Object and show it into the Title of the JFrame

Tags: java, swing, oop, arraylist, jframe

I wanna take the Name of my first Object in my ArrayList, but I really dont know how I do this. This name that I take should be the title of my JFrame.

This is my JFrame:

```
public class TransactionFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
private Transaction trans;
private Bank bank;
private Customer customer;
private Account acc;
private Toolkit t;
private int x=0, y=0, width=800, height = 600;

public TransaktionFrame(Konto konto) throws HeadlessException {
    super();
    this.konto = konto;
    t = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Dimension d = t.getScreenSize();
    x = (int)((d.getWidth() - width) / 2);
    y = (int)((d.getHeight()- height)/ 2);

    setTitle("Application Java" );

    setBounds(x, y, width, height);
    setVisible(true);
}
}
```

The next one is my class Menue with an Method called InitOfObjects

```
public class Menue {

private Bank bank = new Bank();
private Account account = new Account();
private Customer customer= new Customer();

   public void initOfObjects(){
    Customer customer1 = new Privatecustomer("Ragnar", "Lothbrok", "017634456657", "Lothbrok@ragnar.de", "15.07.1979",
    new Adress("Ragnarstraße", "22", "12159", "Berlin"), "2");
    bank.addCustomer(customer1);

    Kunde customer2 = new Companycustomer("Varian", "Lothbrok", "017634456657", "Lothbrok@ragnar.de", "15.07.1979",
    new Adress("Ragnarstraße", "22", "12159", "Berlin"), "2");
    bank.addCustomer(customer2);

    Customer customer3 = new Privatecustomer("Rengar", "Lothbrok", "017634456657", "Lothbrok@ragnar.de", "15.07.1979",
    new Adress("Ragnarstraße", "22", "12159", "Berlin"), "2");
    bank.addCustomer(customer3);
 }
}
```

My Bank class:

```
public class Bank {

private String name;
private String bic;
private Adress adress;
private ArrayList<Customer> customerList;

public Bank() {
    super();
    this. customerList = new ArrayList<Customer>();
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getbIC() {
    return bic;
}// end of getbIC()

public void setbIC(String bic) {
    this.bic = bic;
}

public Adress getAdress() {
    return adress;
}

public void setAdress(Adress adress) {
    this.adress = adress;
}

public int sizeOfArraylist(){
    return customerList.size();
}

public Customer get(int index){
    return customerList.get(index);

}

public ArrayList<Customer> getCustomerList() {
    return customerList;
}// end of getCustomerList()

public void setCustomerList(ArrayList<Customer> customerList) {
    this. customerList = customerList;
}

public boolean addAccount(Account account) {
    for (Customer c : customerList) {
        if (c.getCustomerNumber().equals(account.getCustomerNb())) {
            boolean sucess = k.addAccount(account);
            return sucess;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public void addCustomer(Customer customer) {
    this.customerList.add(customer);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Bank [Name= " + name + ", BIC= " + bic + ", Adress= " + adress + ", Customer= " + customerList + " ]";
}

}
```

My Customer class:

```
public class Customer implements Comparator<Customer> {

protected String customerNumber;
private Adress adress;
protected ArrayList<Account> account;


public Customer(String cnb, Adress adress) {
    super();
    this.customerNumber = cnb;
    this.adress = adress;
}

public Customer(String customerNumber) {
    this.customerNumber = customerNumber;
}

public Customer() {

}

public Adress getAdress() {
    return adress;
}

public void setAdress(Adress adress) {
    this.adress = adress;
}

public String getCustomerNumber() {
    return customerNumber;
}

public Customer setCustomerNumber(String customerNumber) {
    this.customerNumber = customerNumber;
    return this;
}

public ArrayList<Account> getAccount() {
    return account;
}


public boolean addAccount(Account acc) {
    if (account == null)
        account = new ArrayList<Account>();


    if (account.size() > 10)
        return false; 


    account.add(k);

    return true;
}


@Override
public int compare(Customer o1, Customer o2) {

    return o1.customerNumber.compareTo(o2.customerNumber);
}

}
```

My Privatecustomer Class (short to relevant):

```
public class Privatecustomer extends Customer {

private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private Adresse adress;
private String customerNumber;

public Privatkunde(String firstname, String lastname, Adress adress, String kndnr) {
    super(kndnr, adress);
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.adresse = adress;
    this.customerNumber = cnb;

} 
public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public String getLastname () {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname (String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public Adress getAdress() {
    return adress;
}

public void setAdress(Adress adress) {
    this.adress = adress;
}

}
```

My Companycustomer Class (short to relevant):

```
public class Companycustomer extends Customer {


private String companyName;
private Adresse adr;

public Companycustomer(String companyName, Adress adress, String customerNumber) {
    super(customerNumber, adress);
    this.companyName = firmenName;
    this.adr = adress;

}

public String getCompanyName() {
    return companyName;
}

public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
    this.companyName = companyName;
}

public Adresse getAdr() {
    return adr;
}

public void setAdr(Adress adr) {
    this.adr = adr;
}
```

The Privatecustomer and Companycustomer extends from Customer.
I just wanna say that the code actually work.
I just want to know how i can take out the name and lastname of customer and the name of the Company Customer.
Why I use Swing, because the teacher said it. I wanna really like to learn javafx but the teacher said no.
If you need more Code just write me. I am really new in Java.

Best Regards
Maskulin

Comment: want to give your a good suggestion, that try to learn some java fx... swing is so bad

Comment: post your `Bank` class code as well.

Comment: Your menu class needs someway to talk to your frame, while some might suggest passing a reference of frame, I'd create an interface which described what other class are allowed to/can do and implement that instead

Comment: `setBounds(x, y, width, height);` would better be `pack();` which makes the frame the size it needs to be, without guessing using magic numbers, followed by `setLocationRelativeTo(null);` to put it in the middle of the screen.

Comment: @xFighter *"..swing is so bad"* Newbies are so poor at judging the quality of a GUI toolkit. Suggest updating from the stable, robust Swing if you will, but don't bad mouth it, since that just underlines that you never learned how to use it.

Comment: Hey guys, I just edit my Post with much more information and why I use Swing. Ty for all that wanna help me

Answer (score 0):

below is pseudo code for same,

```
Menue  menu = new Menue();
menu.initOfObjects();//populate list of customers

Bank bankObj=menu.getBank();
List<Customer> customers=bankObj.getCustomers();//get List of customers

if(customers!=null && customers.size()>0)
setTitle(customers.get(0).getCustomerName() );//get First customer details
```

Comment: I just edit my Post because I haven`t the Name of Customer in the class customer. Its in the classes Companycustomer and Privatecustomer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure about your complete question, but I think I know what you want, so I'll use some imagination in order to answer you.

I'll assume that the ArrayList you are talking about is in the field bank of class **Bank** and you are storing all the accounts through **Menue** class, so first step is to create a getter in both classes:

```
public class Bank {

    ...

    ArrayListz<Customer> list;

    public int size()
    {
        return list.size();
    }

    // Notice that this WILL ASSUME that index is < than size
    public Customer get(int index)
    {
        return list.get(index);
    }
}

public class Menue {

...

    public Customer getCustomer(int index)
    {
        // If element exists at 'index', return it. If it doesn't, return null
        return index >= bank.size() ? null : bank.get(index);
    }

}
```

You need **Customer** fields values, so you will need to do something like above but in the right class. Now, you can access to all the info you need, so assuming you have the field *bank* correctly initialized in your JFrame class, you can do something like this:

```
public class TransactionFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private Bank bank;
    ...

    public TransaktionFrame(Konto konto) throws HeadlessException {
        super();
        ...

        //this will return the name of the first customer    
        Customer customer = bank.getCustomer(0);
        String name = customer == null ? "" : customer.getName();

        ...

        setTitle(name); //this will use the name of your the first customer as the title of the JFrame

    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this solve your problem, but I hope it helps :)

Comment: I just edit my course. I understand you way to fix it, but the customer has not the name. Name is on class Privatecustomer and Companycustomer.

Comment: Also I get a Nullpointerexception on the class of TransactionFrame in the line Customer customer = bank.getCustomer(0);.